# Extraction of data from Soap Response in Php

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing, soap-client

I did a **SOAP/WSDL** request with a **PHP script**.
I could access an answer which look like this :

```
stdClass Object
(
     [inventory] => 
     (
        [0] => stdClass Object
               (
                [location_inventory] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [location] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [organization] => abcdef
                                [contact] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [contact_details] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => Thomas
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [product] => tomatoes
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

The point is that I can't extract the variables  "organization", "id", or "product".

What is the difference of syntax when accessing a **stdClass Object** or an **Array** ?

Comment: `$data->inventory[0]->location_inventory->location->organization` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are using `json_decode` to have the object you showed.
If that is the case, try using `json_decode( $data, true);` which will return a proper array as described in the docs: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

That way you will be able to access your data the normal array way: $data['inventory']...

Hope that helps